# assigning value to a 2d array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i have a 2d array

```
$arr = array (
array('x'=>'x1' , 'y'=>'') ,
array('x'=>'x2' , 'y'=>'') 
);
```

as you can see the y column is empty

if i want to put some value on it this doesn't works

```
foreach($arr as $a )
{
  if($a['x'] == 'x1')
   $a['y'] = 'y1';

  if($a['x'] == 'x2')
   $a['y'] = 'y2';
}
```

i know i can use 2 `for` loops , but i was wondering if there is a cleaner/simpler way like foreach to do this ? my application already uses the froeach loop to check some column in array and it's messy enough already i don't need 2 other loops !

Comment: it's doesn't i am not got your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using the array values instead of the keys.  The following code will do it:

```
<?php
$arr = array (
array('x'=>'x1' , 'y'=>'') ,
array('x'=>'x2' , 'y'=>'') 
);
foreach($arr as $key => $value )
{
  if($arr[$key]['x'] == 'x1')
   $arr[$key]['y'] = 'y1';

  if($arr[$key]['x'] == 'x2')
   $arr[$key]['y'] = 'y2';
}
?>
```

As you can see, you should use the $key => $value notation for foreach.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `foreach($arr as &$a)`, which will then work, because you're now requiring the reference to the array's element, and not its value stored in a new variable, which occured in your case. ;-)